# Using .kitchen.yml how do I specify multiple ssh keys?

Tags: chef-infra, assembla

I'm using Kitchen / ChefDK to deploy to EC2. In the .yml I specify my amazon keys which get transferred to the instance when I run kitchen converge. I'm also deploying from git and have recently swapped over to assembla which hosts the repository. Is it possible in the kitchen.yml to specify a 2nd ssl key (the assembla git key) to be transferred to my instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test-kitchen doesn't "transfer the Amazon keys" to anything, it just uses them to connect to the AWS API to launch the VM. All the actual configuration on the machine is handled by Chef using the recipes you specified. You can certainly make a recipe to write out multiple deploy keys, but that isn't done via kitchen.yml.